# How to upload images in Next.js13 and get image data in route.js file

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, upload

This is the code for my front-end!

```
  const handleImageChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('image', file)
    const res = await fetch(SENT_IMG_MESSAGE, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
      params: {
        fromId: session?.user.id,
        toId: createNewChat._id
      },
      body: formData
    })
  };
```

This is the code from my app API route()

```
export const POST = async (req, {params}) => {
  try {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(), {status: 200})
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response('发送图片-服务端处理时发生了问题!', {status: 500})
  }
}
```

I have tried many methods, but unfortunately none of them have been successful!
for example

```
    const res = await req.json()
    console.log(res)
```

```
    const res = await req.body
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.